# Undefined property: stdClass::$migration when using SQLite (php artisan migrate)

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, lumen

Running `php artisan migrate` throws `Undefined property: stdClass::$migration`, causing no tables to be created.

I am using `sqlite`. My `.env` simply has: `DB_CONNECTION=sqlite`.
I created a `config/database.php` which contains:

```
    'connections' => [
        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => storage_path('database.sqlite'), // Make sure this file exists.
            'prefix' => '',
        ],
    ],
```

I have a simple migration with two columns.

So far I have tried everything from creating a new composer project to reinstall PHP.

The full exception:

```
 () at C:\Development\Repositories\phpchat\vendor\illuminate\database\Query\Builder.php:2360
 Laravel\Lumen\Application->Laravel\Lumen\Concerns\{closure}() at C:\Development\Repositories\phpchat\vendor\illuminate\database\Query\Builder.php:2360
 Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->pluckFromObjectColumn() at C:\Development\Repositories\phpchat\vendor\illuminate\database\Query\Builder.php:2332
 Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->pluck() at C:\Development\Repositories\phpchat\vendor\illuminate\database\Migrations\DatabaseMigrationRepository.php:53
 Illuminate\Database\Migrations\DatabaseMigrationRepository->getRan() at C:\Development\Repositories\phpchat\vendor\illuminate\database\Migrations\Migrator.php:90
 Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator->run() at C:\Development\Repositories\phpchat\vendor\illuminate\database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand.php:71
 Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand->handle() at n/a:n/a
 call_user_func_array() at C:\Development\Repositories\phpchat\vendor\illuminate\container\BoundMethod.php:32
 Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}() at C:\Development\Repositories\phpchat\vendor\illuminate\container\BoundMethod.php:90
 Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod() at C:\Development\Repositories\phpchat\vendor\illuminate\container\BoundMethod.php:34
 Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call() at C:\Development\Repositories\phpchat\vendor\illuminate\container\Container.php:580
 Illuminate\Container\Container->call() at C:\Development\Repositories\phpchat\vendor\illuminate\console\Command.php:183
 Illuminate\Console\Command->execute() at C:\Development\Repositories\phpchat\vendor\symfony\console\Command\Command.php:255
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at C:\Development\Repositories\phpchat\vendor\illuminate\console\Command.php:170
 Illuminate\Console\Command->run() at C:\Development\Repositories\phpchat\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:908
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at C:\Development\Repositories\phpchat\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:269
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at C:\Development\Repositories\phpchat\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:145
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at C:\Development\Repositories\phpchat\vendor\illuminate\console\Application.php:90
 Illuminate\Console\Application->run() at C:\Development\Repositories\phpchat\vendor\laravel\lumen-framework\src\Console\Kernel.php:115
 Laravel\Lumen\Console\Kernel->handle() at C:\Development\Repositories\phpchat\artisan:35
```

Comment: what does your migration file look like?

Comment: @khartnett it is very simple, but it was not part of the issue. See my answer below for the solution :)

Comment: huh, that is interesting. Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that when you are using SQLite, your `config/database.php` file needs to be slightly more elaborate. Specifically, I needed to add **`'migrations' => 'migrations'`**, which (after hours of searching) solved the problem. My `database.php` file now looks like this:

```
        <?php

    // Adapted from here to use SQLite: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/database.php
    return [
        'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlite'),
        'connections' => [
            'sqlite' => [
                'driver' => 'sqlite',
                'database' => storage_path('database.sqlite'), // Make sure this file exists.
                'prefix' => '',
            ],
        ],
        'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS, // Returns DB objects in an array format.
        'migrations' => 'migrations'
    ];
```